# While loop to maximise password attempts - Python 3

Tags: python

I'm practising my coding - pretty new to this - and i'm trying to create a login system, all is working well so far but i'm trying to use a while loop to maximise the number of user attempts at inputting the correct password. Even if the user inputs the correct password, the loop will carry on until the loop is completed and will continue to say carry on.

```
login = {
    "alex": "dog123"
}
passkey = login.values()
correct_user = True


while correct_user:
    user = input("Please input your username ")
    if user in login:
        print(f'Hello {user}, please input your password.')
        correct_user = False
    else:
        print("Invalid user")

attempt = 0
max_attempts = 3
correct_password = True

while correct_password:
    password = input(">")
    if password in passkey:
        print(f"""Welcome back {user}! 
How can i help you today?""")
        correct_password = False
    else:   
        while attempt < max_attempts:
            print("try again")
            attempt += 1
            password = input(">")
            if password in passkey:
                correct_password = False
        else:
            print("too many guesses!")
            break
```

Comment: You break out of the inner `while` loop, but the outer one still runs; only use the inner loop.

Comment: Not what your asked, but your code accepts the password of any user, when it checks `if password in passkey`, instead of requiring the password of that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from breaking out of the inner `while` loop but still having the outer one running; it's better to use only one loop (and you don't need the 'correct_password' flag any more):

```
attempt = 0
max_attempts = 3
passkey = ['sesame']

while attempt < max_attempts:
    password = input(">")
    if password in passkey:
        print(f"""Welcome back {user}! How can i help you today?""")
        break
    else:
        attempt += 1
        if attempt < max_attempts:
            print("try again")    
else:
    print("too many guesses!")
```

As a side note, codester_09 is right about the way you check the password, so implement their modification too.

Comment: Thank you, much shorter than my version!

Comment: How does this answer your question?

Comment: `if attempt <3:` is not even necessary

Comment: It's necessary to avoid "try again" on the last attempt :) ; alex: it's just a little shorter (I didn't reproduce the username part), that is still relevant.

Comment: But the code will automatically avoid `try again` once `while attempt < max_attempts:` is fulfilled.

Comment: Not so: try my code without the 'if' and you'll see. When attempt reaches 3, the print("try again") will be executed, THEN while ... < ... will be tested and fail.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
login = {
    "alex": "dog123"
}
passkey = login.values()
correct_user = True


while correct_user:
    user = input("Please input your username ")
    if user in login:
        print(f'Hello {user}, please input your password.')
        correct_user = False
    else:
        print("Invalid user")

attempt = 0
max_attempts = 3
correct_password = True

while correct_password:
    if attempt < max_attempts: # checks if an attempt is left.
        password = input(">")
        if password == login[user]: # Check password equal current userpassword.
            print(f"""Welcome back {user}! 
    How can I help you today?""")
            correct_password = False
        else:
            print("Invalid password")
            attempt += 1
    else: # print too many attempts 
        print("Too many attempts")
        correct_password = False
```

---

Don't use `password in passkey` to check that if password is correct or not. Why?

##### Explanation

Let say you have more than one users

```
login = {
    "alex": "dog123",
    "alice": "cat123"

}
```

If you use `in` and check that if password is in passwords list then you face a bug

When

1. Example

- If user is equal `alex` and password is `cat123` then you code don't print that password is incorrect.

So use `==` and check if `password == login[user]` here user and password are the one that user enters.

---

***"@alex comments. what does the '[user]' aspect mean?"*.**

@alex if you want all values from the dictionary then you use `dict.values()`, But if you want a specific key's value then you use `dict['Key']` or `dict.get('Key')`. Let's say `user='alex'` then `login[user]` gives the value of the user from the `login` `dict` which is `'dog123'`. Note if the `user` is not in the `dict` then it will give you a `KeyError`. But if you use `dict.get(user)` it will return the value of user or None if `user` is not in `dict`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But what does the '[user]' aspect mean? is that the first part of the key pair?

Comment: _"what does the '[user]' aspect mean"_. @alex if you want all values from the dictionary then you use `dict.values()`, But if you want a specific key's value then you use `dict['Key']` or `dict.get('Key')`. Let's say `user='alex'` then `login[user]` gives the value of the user from the `login` `dict` which is `'dog123'`. Note if the `user` is not in the `dict` then it will give you a `KeyError`. But if you use `dict.get(user)` it will return the value of user or None if `user` is not in `dict`